# setting and accessing class variables in dart not working as expected

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class in dart

```
class myClass {

String var1 = '';

void method1 {
  var1 = "Test"
}

void method2 {
  print(this.var1);
}
```

Why does the print of the second method not print anything? What is it I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depends on how you call it

```
myClass myclass = myClass();
myclass.method1();
myclass.method2();
```

this got to work fine

Comment: This is the way I am doing it now, but just wondering why is the other way not working.

Comment: The way I mentioned it in the post. I am calling those methods from a widget class this way myClass().method1() and myClass().method2() on button clicks.

Comment: @Sumchans it is working but it is empty. every time you call myClass(). it creates a new instance of that class ....so it means  myClass().method1() is working on another object and myClass().method2() working on another object

Comment: Thanks Ardeshir for taking the time to explain it to me. I was being super dump here.

Answer (score 1):

your code have some problems! you should provide `methodName()` parenthesis after method name in class definition:

```
  class MyClass {

String var1 = '';

void method1() {
  this.var1 = "Test";
}

void method2() {
  print(this.var1);
}
}
```

then you can create an object as follow:

```
myClass t = new myClass();
  
  print(t.var1);
  t.method1();
  t.method2();
```

Comment: Oh I am sorry, that is already there, that was just a typo.

Comment: your welcome, also please note that we should use uppercase for class name!

Answer (score 1):

It is printing but it is printing an empty string ("").
Your code has too many mistakes, you have to add parasynthesis() after the function name.

secondly you have to call the method1 function first that will set the var1 value to "test". after that call method2.
Here is the code, I'm attaching.

```
class myClass {

String var1 = '';

void method1() {
  var1 = "Test";
}

void method2 (){
  print(this.var1);
}

}

void main(){
  var obj = myClass();
  obj.method1();
  obj.method2();
}
```